# How to fix Cursor initialization error in android?

Tags: java, android

my inv.db has following content

select * from inventory;

```
id|name|supplier|quanity|price

1|Product 1|Wallmart|10|50
2|Product 1|Wallmart|10|50
```

However i get the error

```
Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 3 columns.
Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

But there are four columns excluding id.

```
// Find the columns of pet attributes that we're interested in
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRO_NAME);
        int priceColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRO_PRICE);
        int quanColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRO_QUAN);
        int supColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRO_SUP);


        // Read the pet attributes from the Cursor for the current pet
        String petName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
        String price = cursor.getString(priceColumnIndex);
        String quantity = cursor.getString(quanColumnIndex); // produces error
```

Im not sure what is wrong here. My code runs if i remove last line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cursor is initialized correctly, but it cannot find a column index for the string at `InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRO_QUAN`

Make sure the string stored there matches what the column name is. Right now it is probably incorrect

Comment: Actually there is 5 columns - but android is seeing only 3 ie id, name and price. But when i run command on terminal i can see all. Column name is all correct. Iv tried manually putting value 3 and 4 for index which produces error

Comment: it prints _id , name and price to logs as column names. But table schema is CREATE TABLE inventory (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT NOT NULL,supplier TEXT,quantity INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,price INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

Comment: @zeeM can you post the code where you initialize your cursor?

Comment: oh sorry, i didnt include the column names in the projections . thank you